# How to concat the column name in the Range method of vba?

Tags: excel, vba

```
startColumn=startRange.Column
endColumn  =endRange.Column 
Range(startColumn & "5" : endColumn & "5")
```

**I want to concatenate both column Name name and row number in  vba ***

Comment: "column name name"?

Comment: Yes column name like "DR" . I have stored the column name in a variable and I want to concat that variable in Range method .Can you help me ?

Comment: Better practice would be to use `Range(Cells(5,startColumn),Cells(5,endColumn  ))`. Because your variables will return a column index number (assuming you assigned them correctly)

Answer (score 0):

The `.Column` property returns the number of the first column in the first area in the specified range, therefor returning a numeric value. So a better practice would be:

```
Range(Cells(5,startColumn),Cells(5,endColumn ))
```

Now to improve your code a little bit it's wise to use explicit sheet references.

```
Dim rng as range
With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheet's CodeName
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(5,startColumn),.Cells(5,endColumn))
End with
```